# C++ template ambiguous instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I am trying to do some interpolation using templates but I get an "ambiguous template instantiation" error. Here is the code

```
// interpolation rules
enum InterRule {trap, rect, trapSum};

// Rectangle rule
template <int n, int k, InterRule rule, class Expr> struct Integration {
    static double integrate(double a, double b){
        return (b-a)/n * Expr::eval(a + (k-1)*(b-a)/n) + Integration<n, k - 1, rule, Expr>::integrate(a,b);
    }
};

// termination case
template <int n, InterRule rule, class Expr> struct Integration<n,0,rule,Expr> {
    static double integrate(double a, double b){
        return 0;
    }
};

// Trapezoidal rule
template <int n, int k, class Expr> struct Integration<n, k, trap, Expr> {
    static double integrate(double a, double b){
        return (b-a)/n * (Expr::eval(a)/2 + Integration<n,k-1,trapSum,Expr>::integrate(a,b) + Expr::eval(b)/2);
    }
};

// Trapezoidal sum
template <int n, int k, class Expr> struct Integration<n, k, trapSum, Expr> {
    static double integrate(double a, double b){
        return Expr::eval(a + k*(b-a)/n) + Integration<n,k-1,trapSum,Expr>::integrate(a,b);
    }
};
```

Basically, I am trying to implement the Trapezoidal rule so that it is statically unrolled. [image]
 However, it appears that the compiler gets confused whether to use "termination case" or "trapezoidal sum". What am I doing wrong and is there a workaround? I want to force it to use "termination case" if `k==0` regardless of the type of `InterRule` rule.

***EDIT***
Additional code to make it run:

```
// the types of expressions (+,-,*, etc.)
enum ExprType { mul, divide, add, sub, constant};

// constant
template <ExprType eType, class Left, class Right, int coeff, int power> struct Expr {
    static double eval(double x){
        return coeff * std::pow(x, power);
    }
};


int main()
{

    double a = 1;
    double b = 2;

    // Expr defines the function f(x) = x
    Integration<50, 50, trap, Expr<constant,int,int,1,1>> inte2;
    std::cout << inte2.integrate(a,b) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a usage example?

Comment: Please provide a [repro]. Your shown code does not instantiate any of the templates. Also "*so that it is statically unrolled*": I am not sure what you mean here. If the only reason you are using templates here is that you think it will run faster, then you will be most likely wrong. The compiler is most likely going to inline everything anyway and then it doesn't matter whether the constant parameters were template arguments or regular function arguments. Also unrolling a loop too much may make the performance *worse*. Let the compiler decide how to handle that.

Comment: Lastly, since C++17, something like this can be done much quicker and cleaner without all the templates using *fold expressions*.

Comment: @walnut I added code to complete the example. I am using templates out of curiosity and to learn them so efficiency is not important.

Comment: @Timo I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to disambiguate adding an additional template parameter.

Maybe something as

```
// .................................................VVVVVVVVVVV
template <int n, int k, InterRule rule, class Expr, bool = true>
struct Integration {
   // ...
};
```

The ground case explicitly with `false`

```
template <int n, InterRule rule, class Expr>
struct Integration<n, 0, rule, Expr, false> { // <--- false !
    static double integrate(double a, double b){
        return 0;
    }
};
```

and adding the right parameter in recursion calls

```
    return (b-a)/n * Expr::eval(a + (k-1)*(b-a)/n)
       + Integration<n, k - 1, rule, Expr, (k>1)>::integrate(a,b);
    // ....................................^^^^^
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

// interpolation rules
enum InterRule {trap, rect, trapSum};

// Rectangle rule
template <int n, int k, InterRule rule, class Expr, bool = true>
struct Integration {
    static double integrate(double a, double b){
        return (b-a)/n * Expr::eval(a + (k-1)*(b-a)/n)
           + Integration<n, k - 1, rule, Expr, (k>1)>::integrate(a,b);
    }
};

// termination case
template <int n, InterRule rule, class Expr>
struct Integration<n, 0, rule, Expr, false> {
    static double integrate(double a, double b){
        return 0;
    }
};

// Trapezoidal rule
template <int n, int k, class Expr>
struct Integration<n, k, trap, Expr> {
    static double integrate(double a, double b){
        return (b-a)/n * (Expr::eval(a)/2
           + Integration<n,k-1,trapSum,Expr,(k>1)>::integrate(a,b)
           + Expr::eval(b)/2);
    }
};

// Trapezoidal sum
template <int n, int k, class Expr>
struct Integration<n, k, trapSum, Expr> {
    static double integrate(double a, double b){
        return Expr::eval(a + k*(b-a)/n)
           + Integration<n,k-1,trapSum,Expr,(k>1)>::integrate(a,b);
    }
};

// the types of expressions (+,-,*, etc.)
enum ExprType { mul, divide, add, sub, constant};

// constant
template <ExprType eType, class Left, class Right, int coeff, int power> struct Expr {
    static double eval(double x){
        return coeff * std::pow(x, power);
    }
};


int main ()
 {

    double a = 1;
    double b = 2;

    // Expr defines the function f(x) = x
    Integration<50, 50, trap, Expr<constant,int,int,1,1>> inte2;
    std::cout << inte2.integrate(a,b) << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Thats clever! Thanks.